# Trying to saveArray, got error - Cannot convert value of type '[Data]' to expected argument type '[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary, typecase

I'm trying to save array added from tableview using this function:

```
class func saveArray(_ value: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>], key: String) {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
    }
```

Below is the function where I want to save the array:

```
func addItemCat(items: [Data]) {
        print("ITEM: ", items)
        dataSource.myListTableViewController.myListArr = items
        self.myListTV.isHidden = false
        UserDefaultsHelper.saveArray(items, key: Constants.myList.myList)
    }
```

However, I got this error: Cannot convert value of type '[Data]' to expected argument type '[Dictionary String, AnyObject ]'

Below is my Data model:
[data model screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yUAu.png)

I'm new to Swift and I hope someone can explain what is the problem.

Comment: The `saveArray` have param type of array of dictionary `[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]`, but you are passing array of Data `[Data]`, clearly it wont work, try change `[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]` to `[Data]`?

Comment: @Tj3n, I've changed it, but still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with data types, `saveArray` function expects value parameter of type array of dictionary `[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]`, but you are passing array of data model objects which is a type-mismatch error.

**To solve this:**

First, You should not use pre-defined keywords for creating your custom object. Use `DataObject` instead:

```
struct DataObject {

}
```

Now change your `saveArray` function as:

```
class func saveArray(_ value: [DataObject], key: String) {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
}
```

and `addItemCat`, function as:

```
func addItemCat(items: [DataObject]) {
    print("ITEM: ", items)
    dataSource.myListTableViewController.myListArr = items
    self.myListTV.isHidden = false
    UserDefaultsHelper.saveArray(items, key: Constants.myList.myList)
}
```